# list indices must be integers or slices, not list from 2D array python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array, error-handling

I get this error from python:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

when using this code:

```
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8 = "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7", "f8", "g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "g5", "g6", "g7", "g8", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8" 
bord = [[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8], [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8], [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8], [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8], [e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8], [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8], [g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8], [h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8]]


for y in bord:
    for x in bord[y]:
        print(bord[y][x])
```

so I have created an 8 by 8 board (2D list) with chess like names for positions.
I want to execute a piece of code for every individual square of the board.

the first for loop will select 1 row at a time (therefor y as y axis)
then the second for loop will select 1 column at a time (therefor x as x axis)

For a test I just printed the position of the 2D list with:

```
print(bord[y][x])
```

Comment: You seem to understand that the first-loop loops over the sublists: "first for loop will select 1 row at a time", so then what do you think `bord[y]` is going to do when `y` **is a sublist**? You want something like `for row in bord: for x in row: print(x)`. Note, this is not a 2dimensional array, this is a list.

Comment: Or, using your variable names: `for y in bord: for x in y: print(x)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you sir! i am quite new to python but you helped me out alot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for y in bord:
    for x in bord[y]:
        print(bord[y][x])
```

This is wrong, the correct way of doing the above is this:

```
for y in bord:
    for x in y:
        print(x)
```

This because `for x in arr` iterates over the array and saves the element in variable `x`, if you wanted to do the style of `bord[y][x]`, do the following:

```
for y in range(len(bord)):
    for x in range(len(bord[y])):
        print(bord[y][x])
```

The `range()` function in this instance creates an array from 0..len(board) - 1, so let's say bord is 5 elements in size, we would be doing `range(5)`. That is the same as doing `for x in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. So it iterates over that array and saves the current element in the variable x.

So just to conclude.

You can do either:

```
for y in bord:
    for x in y:
        print(x)
```

or

```
for y in range(len(bord)):
    for x in range(len(bord[y])):
        print(bord[y][x])
```

You can use either, whichever you prefer. There is probably a reason for using one or the other but I am unaware of it, if someone wants to edit this to provide that reason please do.

Hope this helps!